# How to Add ImageObject Schema on All Images Attached with Product?

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, structured-data, woocommerce

I have **multiple images in a single product** in the `post_content` area. These are attached to the product but without using the **gallery** feature.

I want to add structured data to each image attached to the product. I use the following code to extract images to an array `$imagess` and then apply **structured data** on each **image with a loop**.

I want to use multiple **Imageobjects** and **product** **schema** on the same page. This code shows a single image **x times of total images**.

```
function wc_add_product_structed_data_images ( $markup ) {
    $imagess = array();
    $imagess = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 99 ) );    

     foreach ( $imagess as $attachment ): 
     $markup['@context'] = 'https://schema.org';
     $markup['@type'] = 'ImageObject';
     $markup['contentUrl'] = $attachment->guid;
     $markup['@context'] = 'https://schema.org/';
     $markup['@type'] = 'ImageObject';
     $markup['contentUrl'] = $attachment->guid
     $markup['license'] = 'https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/';
     $markup['acquireLicensePage'] = 'https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/';
     $markup['creditText'] = 'Creative Department';
     $markup['copyrightNotice'] = '© 2008 to 2022';
     $markup['@context'] = 'https://schema.org/';
     $markup['ImageObject']['@type'] = 'CreativeWork';
     $markup['ImageObject']['creator'] = 'abc';
     $markup['embeddedTextCaption'] = 'emb text caption';
return $markup;
      }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_context', 'wc_add_product_structed_data_images', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What I understand from your question**, you’ve already generated product schema via Woocommerce and you want to append/insert additional **multiple** `ImageObject` - for **ALL** the images **attached** (added within the content/product long description/etc./no-gallery images) to the **product** - **within** generated product schema.

---

**Before heading to the solution, these are the issues with your code:**

- foreach clause is not closed
- `creator` object **type** can be **Organization** or **Person** only which both belongs to **CreativeWork** category. Use the object type i-e: Organization or Person, not the CreativeWork category name here since it’ll fail rich results test.
- In `contentUrl`, you are using only **guid** which is **not an URL**. guid is only a unique identifier, however, **markup needs full URL** to the attachment.
- Use **ACTUAL** **context** in the filter hook name i-e: **product**. So instead of `woocommerce_structured_data_context` use `woocommerce_structured_data_product` . If you leave generic word context, it will override markup for all context like breadcrumb and others. Keep your context specifically product for product related images.
- In schema, you don't need to enforce `orderby` and `order`, so clean them from `get_children` arguments
- Since you want `ImageObject` markup for **ALL** attachments, clean out the `posts_per_page` too from arguments.

---

**Solution (Tested, Validated, & Vetted for Recommended Usage)**

The solution is tested with latest (up to the date) Woocommerce, Wordpress, and also validated with Google Rich Results testing tool.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'wc_add_product_structed_data_images', 10, 1 );
function wc_add_product_structed_data_images ( $markup ) {
    $images = array(); //replaced ss with s
    $images = get_children( 
        array( 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') 
    );  

    if(count($images) > 0) { // just ensuring we really have childrens or additional images
        
        /** prepare image objects before insertion */
        $imageObjects = array();
        foreach($images as $i) {
            //Prepare the single image meta data
            $singleImageObject = array(
                "@type" => "ImageObject",
                "name" => "Name of the image",         
                "creator" => array(
                    "@type" => "Organization",
                    "name" => "Name of Creator"
                ),      
                "creditText" => "Creative Dept.",
                "embeddedTextCaption" => "The caption of image.",
                "description" => "The short description of the image.",
                "contentUrl" => wp_get_attachment_url($i->ID),
                "license" => "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/",
                "acquireLicensePage" => "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/",
                "copyrightNotice" => "2008 to 2022"
            );
            /** Pushing image to image objects */ 
            $imageObjects[] = $singleImageObject; 
        }
        /** Based on image property existence, lets push the objects in markup now */
        if(isset($markup['image'])) { //if it is set, it returns an URL string only; not ImageObject. 
                $markup['image'] = array($markup['image']); //converting to array while preserving first image added by woo
                $markup['image'][] = $imageObjects;
        } else { //if no image property is yet set, lets set it and add ImageObject array
            $markup['image'] = array(); 
            $markup['image'][] = $imageObjects;
        }

        return $markup;
    }

    return $markup;
}
```

**Code Explanation**

- I changed the filter hook from `context` to `product` and cleaned the arguments.
- Firstly: If we really have attachments, I prepared the `ImageObject` markup by looping through all images, creating an `ImageObject` associate array `$singleImageObject` for individual image, and then pushing/merging all of the `ImageObject` into one array `$imageObjects`.
- Secondly: The image property might already be set by Woo for featured image and if it sets it in string format. It means, we must **either append** the image property **or we should override** it completing by adding featured image and additional ones. In the above code, I checked if we've the image property set, I converted the data type to array (since if it set already it is string), then I pushed back the existing string URL for featured image to preserve it, and finally pushed/appended the prepared `$imageObjects` into the `$markup['image']`

---

**Additional Notes**

- In the ImageObject markup, you can replace image name, creator name and type (Organization or Person) only, embeddedTextCaption with image caption, and other properties to their respective dynamic or static values or as needed.
- If you're developing a theme with it and using this filter, make sure your theme uses `wp_footer()` in the footer since this filter uses `wp_footer` hook to output its contents.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked ...

Comment: Your welcome. :)